# c# wpf CanExecuteChanged property changed on different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, command

I have a problem that the CanExecuteChanged is not done when I change a property. I pretty much figured out why. However I am not really sure how to fix it. The issue apparently comes from changing the property on a different thread.

My code..
Command:

```
class StartTestCommand : ICommand
{
    private MainViewModel viewModel;

    public StartTestCommand(MainViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        bool canExecute = true;
        if (viewModel.SerialPortNo==null)
        {
            canExecute = false;
        }
        if (viewModel.IsTestRunning)
        {
            canExecute = false;
        }
        return canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { viewModel.StartTest(); });
    }
}
```

And the thing that is called on a separate thread:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Start the testing
    /// </summary>
    public void StartTest()
    {
        StartSerial();
        ExecuteSelectedTests();
        StopSerial();
    }

/// <summary>
    /// start serial communication
    /// </summary>
    private void StartSerial()
    {
        serialManager.Start(serialPortNo);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// stop serial communication
    /// </summary>
    private void StopSerial()
    {
        serialManager.Stop();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// runs the selected tests
    /// </summary>
    private void ExecuteSelectedTests()
    {
        this.IsTestRunning = true;
        foreach (var item in testItemsToRunCollection)
        {
            item.Execute();
        }
        this.IsTestRunning = false;
    }
```

So the IsTestRunning is set from another thread. I would like to know what would be the correct way of fixing this problem :)

Comment: Ideally when should be "IsTestRunning=false"? Is it when ALL of the test item have completed execution, or when AT LEAST ONE has completed execution?

Comment: All the items. There is a chance that on specific conditions in can take even few hours.

Comment: What is the type of "testItemsToRunCollection" ? Also, can you run item.Execute() in parallel? If they don't have any dependency on each other.

Comment: type of testItemsToRunCollection is ObservableCollection of custom class objects. It would not be possbible to run them in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dispatch the code to be run on the UI thread like this:

```
 Dispatcher.Invoke(((Action)(() => ]
      {
         this.IsTestRunning = false;
         CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
      })));
```

Comment: It won't block UI? Because that thread has a lot to do. will be running for at least few minutes up to hours

Comment: youre just dispatching the value change, so no

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry didn't catch that. I guess that it would be the most reasonable solution :) Thanks a lot

Comment: hmm: i replaced this.IsTestRunning = true; with Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(((Action)(() => this.IsTestRunning = true))); Still doesn't work though

Comment: try adding `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` to the dispatched code

Comment: Yay. That did the trick. Final code: ` Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(((Action)(() => { this.IsTestRunning = false; CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); }))); `